# my document has no title - my url is displayed as title

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, mysqli

it is such that I have not shown title and keywords and description,

but if I print my php code away so it works just fine but if I add php'en it does not work in some manner.

I have 3 posts in the database.

here click im to it site;

```
<?php
$sql = 
"
SELECT fms_forum.id, fms_forum.title, fms_forum.url, fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_bruger.profilbillede
FROM fms_forum
INNER JOIN fms_bruger
ON fms_forum.brugerid=fms_bruger.id
";
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $url, $fornavn, $efternavn, $profilbillede);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr class="postbox">
        <td><a href="/forum/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $url;?>/"><?php echo $title;?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]+)/([^/.]*)/?$ /forum-s.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

it title on my site;

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT title, info FROM fms_forum WHERE url = ?')) 

{ 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $url);
    $url = $_get["url"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $info);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="hey">
    <meta name="keywords" content="hey">
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
```

[image]

Here you can see how the title appears with the code,

if I udkommentar php code and just write something for so it works just fine.

But what I need to get to the ID of the post that is,

its here from my database;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fms_forum` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(156) NOT NULL,
  `indhold` longtext NOT NULL,
  `brugerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Data dump for tabellen `fms_forum`
--

INSERT INTO `fms_forum` (`id`, `title`, `url`, `info`, `indhold`, `brugerid`) VALUES
(1, 'Velkommen til tasakker - Sjælland', 'velkommentiltraenigsmakkersjaelland', 'Velkommen til tasakker - Sjælland, Du har mulighed få at find en makker i dit område.', '<p><span style="font-family: Arial, ''Times New Roman''; font-size: medium;">P&aring; Tr&aelig;ningsmakker &ndash; sj&aelig;lland har du mulighed for at finde en makker i dit omr&aring;de, som tr&aelig;ner med samme m&aring;l og samme antal ugentlige tr&aelig;ninger</span></p>', 1),
(2, 'Velkommen til trasakker - Sjælland', 'velkommen-til-traenigsmakker---sjaelland', 'Velkommen til trasmakker - Sjælland, Du har mulighed få at find en makker i dit område.', '<p>hjheryre yrey</p>', 1),
(3, 'Velkommen til trasmakker - Sjælland', 'velkommentiltraenigsmakkersjaelland', 'herherh', '<p>reh rehre hre reh</p>', 1);
```

I HAVE COMPLETE ITS NOW::

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT title, info FROM fms_forum WHERE fms_forum.id = ?')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($title, $info);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="hey">
        <meta name="keywords" content="hey">
        <?php
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
```

Comment: Do you check $title contain proper value after while loop ?

Comment: @PareshThummar there are not disclosed on the page at all.

Comment: @PareshThummar where I say **$id = $ _GET["id"];** go wrong but if I write **$id = 1** then comes up title without any problems.

Comment: Try this 
$id = $ _GET["id"];
if(!isset($id) || $id == "") echo "Error"; exit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really doing on that way change

```
$stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
 $id = $_GET["id"];

to 

 $id = $_GET["id"];
 $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
```